# 64 bit Number to 2x 32 Bit

Tags: c++, numbers, int, 64-bit

I got a 19 digit number (64 bit and ALWAYS 19 digits) and have to convert that to 2 32 bit int.

the 2 32 bit have to be able to convert back to the 19 digit number.

Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by shifting:

```
#include "stdio.h"

uint64_t bigNum = 5678216589648569852;
uint64_t merged = 0;

uint32_t partA = 0;
uint32_t partB = 0;

//split
partA |= bigNum;
partB |= bigNum >> 32;

//merge
merged = partB;
merged <<= 32;
merged |= partA;
```

Comment: Right-shifting a signed integer is implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: I think it's no big deal here. Maybe if the 32-bit ones are used in between splitting and merging. If the content of the 32-bit ints is not used, it shouldn't matter imo. I *guess* the splitting is just to send the int with some protocol that only supports 32 bit.

Comment: There is also another problem with using signed integers. If `partA` or `partB` end up being negative, that will affect higher bits in `a64` or `b64`, which will give an erroneous result. As a general rule, always use `unsigned` integers for bitwise operations.

Comment: @owacoder well thats right. i changed it to uint now. thanks